# How to change the default action to "open in new tab" when clicked on an attachment in xpages?

Tags: file, download, tabs, xpages, attachment

I have an xpage with a "File Download" control in it, binded to a data source which is pretty basic.  When its displayed and I click on an attachment in the list from a computer / laptop, it downloads it as expected (When you click on the downloaded thing in the bar below the browser, it opens the attachment in the appropriate application).

But when I use this feature from mobile (phone or a tablet), the attachment is opened in the same page directly.  Only when I click on it for a longer period (I'm using an IPhone in this case), I have the option to "Open in New Tab" (as if I "right-clicked" in desktop).

Now what I want to do is, when I click on an attachment from mobile, I want the default action to open it in a new tab.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=765C8DB0E2884CCC8525799E006DAC28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer put me in the correct path but I'm not quite where I want to be.

This answer works when I extend the Bootstrap3_flat theme (which is the selected application theme in xsp.properties) and add the required code. Then when I use the file download control, attachments are opened in new tab by default.

But in xps.properties of the application, I am selecting "Mobile default" for the mobile theme.  So in order to extend "Mobile default" I guess I have to extend "iphone" but when I try that, my application is not loaded correctly.

How can I extend "Mobile default" theme correctly for my application to load correctly?

Comment: "Mobile default" is an early theme designed for XPages mobile controls, before Bootstrap was added for a better user experience. XPages mobile controls were effectively deprecated some years ago. If this is a new application, just use the Bootstrap theme. If it's an older application and you don't want to switch themes, you'll need to create a new Renderer to output the modified HTML (requiring strong Java skills), create a Theme extending mobile, and map the new Renderer you've created to the download control. There are various resources on XPages plugin development.

Comment: A relevant version of XPages Extension Library code is open sourced https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/. All plugins are at https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/tree/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins, where you'll see the bootstrap one. There are no simple steps of what you need to do. You will need to dig into the code and understand what it's doing, to work out what you need to build.